# amplify init (headless) always pushes to aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

im trying to do an `amplify init` in jenkins job. so this needs to be done headless. 
taking inspiration from the [code repo](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/blob/multienv/packages/amplify-cli/sample-headless-scripts/headless_init_env.sh)

i have prepared this code

```
# #!/bin/bash
set -e
IFS='|'
AWSCLOUDFORMATIONCONFIG="{\
\"configLevel\":\"general\",\
\"useProfile\":false,\
\"accessKeyId\":\"${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}\",\
\"secretAccessKey\":\"${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}\",\
\"region\":\"${region}\"\
}"

AMPLIFY="{\"envName\":\"${AMPLIFY_ENV}\", \"defaultEditor\":\"code\"}"
PROVIDERS="{\"awscloudformation\":$AWSCLOUDFORMATIONCONFIG}"

echo 'Initializing Amplify'
amplify init \
--amplify $AMPLIFY \
--providers $PROVIDERS \
--yes
echo 'Amplify Initialized'
```

the question is that doing an `amplify init` from console does not push the resources to cloud. 
but doing an `amplify init` (headless) way. even if an existing environment is used every change is pushed to the cloud.

What im trying to achieve it to create/generate the `API.service.ts` file so that my team does not have to include it in the repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `--yes` was the issue.

this works

```
# #!/bin/bash
set -e
IFS='|'
AWSCLOUDFORMATIONCONFIG="{\
\"configLevel\":\"general\",\
\"useProfile\":false,\
\"accessKeyId\":\"${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}\",\
\"secretAccessKey\":\"${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}\",\
\"region\":\"${region}\"\
}"

AMPLIFY="{\"envName\":\"${AMPLIFY_ENV}\", \"defaultEditor\":\"code\"}"
PROVIDERS="{\"awscloudformation\":$AWSCLOUDFORMATIONCONFIG}"

echo 'Initializing Amplify'
amplify init \
--amplify $AMPLIFY \
--providers $PROVIDERS
echo 'Amplify Initialized'
```